# Invite Facebook friends to the website using App

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I am building a website where user can login using Facebook auth process.
I registered an application on Facebook and I am using PHP SDK from Facebook.

Once user confirmed application's request to use his/her data, user logging in to the website so I can take user's data from Facebook using `facebook->api('/me')` method.

Now, I have a list of user's friends who is not using this application yet, I have it using `facebook->api('/me/taggable_friends')` method. As a result, I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => AaKuxshE8TMxnaW7Yoj7_kEy3k81lgT7EV5UxPjVSJGj1BPhhC2lou-QG1ZQiDGLUCERyx8Bt7zYFzgj1AhwMxCNGNi27xwLkito-Dd0Q3jt5A
            [name] => Name 1
            [picture] => Array
                (
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [is_silhouette] => 
                            [url] => URL
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => AaJjlf3EOvj07Gli0yqyjNB0sj1BUKw8CRo0-3Yr5Vl6GH5XoCW1srNqloxymqeW2x22sTLLtF3wquaX1__YToAlaEbORXSkIxN4mpB6tm491A
            [name] => Name 2
            [picture] => Array
                (
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [is_silhouette] => 
                            [url] => URL
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

How can I invite them to the website using Facebook PHP SDK or something else? Is there any way I could send them a message or tag them somehow so they can receive my link to the website?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq say:

> You may use the Message Dialog on iOS and Android, or the Send Dialog
>   on Web. These products let a person send a message directly to their
>   friends containing a link to your app. This type of message is a great
>   channel for communicating with a smaller number of people in a direct
>   way. The Message Dialog and the Send Dialog both include a typeahead
>   which lets the person easily select a number of friends to receive the
>   invite.